# Stop running Azure Data Factory Pipeline when it is still running

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

I have a `Azure Data Factory Pipeline`. My trigger has been set for every each 5 minutes. 
Sometimes my Pipeline takes more than 5 mins to finished its jobs. In this case, Trigger runs again and creates another instance of my Pipeline and two instances of the same pipeline make problem in my ETL.
How can I be sure than just one instance of my pipeline runs at time?

[image]

As you can see there are several instances running of my pipelines

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few options I could think of:

**OPT 1**

Specify 5 min timeout on your pipeline activities:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-policy

**OPT 2**

1) Create a 1 row 1 column sql RunStatus table: 1 will be our "completed", 0 - "running" status

2) At the end of your pipeline add a stored procedure activity that would set the bit to 1.

3) At the start of your pipeline add a lookup activity to read that bit.

4) The output of this lookup will then be used in if condition activity:

- if 1 - start the pipeline's job, but before that add another stored procedure activity to set our status bit to 0.
- if 0 - depending on the details of your project: do nothing, add a wait activity, send an email, etc.

To make a full use of this option, you can turn the table into a log, where the new line with start and end time will be added after each successful run (before initiating a new run, you can check if the previous run had the end time). Having this log might help you gather data on how much does it take to run your pipeline and perhaps either add more resources or increase the interval between the runs.

**OPT 3**

Monitor the pipeline run with SDKs (have not tried that, so this is just to possibly direct you):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically

Hopefully you can use at least one of them

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to run a process more or less constantly, which is a good fit for [tumbling window triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#tumbling-window-trigger). You can create a dependency such that the trigger is dependent on itself - so it won't run until the previous run has completed.

Start by [creating a trigger that runs a pipeline on a tumbling window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger), then [create a tumbling window trigger dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tumbling-window-trigger-dependency). The section at the bottom of that article discusses ["tumbling window self-dependency properties"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tumbling-window-trigger-dependency#tumbling-window-self-dependency-properties), which shows you what the code should look like once you've successfully set this up.

Comment: This recommendation solved my particular case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the concurrency of the pipeline to 1.

Link: https://www.datastackpros.com/2020/05/prevent-azure-data-factory-from-running.html

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that the recurrence is too frequent under these circumstances. If the graph you shared is all for the same pipeline, then most of them take close to 5 minutes, but you have some that take 30, 40, even 60 minutes. Situations like this are when a simple recurrence trigger probably isn't sufficient. What is supposed to happen while the 60 minute one is running? There will be 10-12 runs that wouldn't start: so they still need to run or can they be ignored?

To make sure all the pipelines run, and manage concurrency, you're going to need to build a queue manager of some kind. ADF cannot handle this itself, so I have built such a system internally and rely on it extensively. I use a combination of Logic Apps, Stored Procedures (Azure SQL), and Azure Functions to queue, execute, and monitor pipeline executions. Here is a high level break down of what you probably need:

1. Logic App 1: runs every 5 minutes and queues an ADF job in the SQL database.
2. Logic App 2: runs every 2-3 minutes and checks the queue to see if a) there is not a job currently running (status = 'InProgress') and 2) there is a job in the queue waiting to run (I do this with a Stored Procedure). IF this state is met: execute the next ADF and update its status to 'InProgress'.

   - I use an Azure Function to submit jobs instead of the built in Logic App activity because I have better control over variable parameters. Also, they can return the newly created ADF RunId, which I rely in #3.
3. Logic App 3: runs every minute and updates the status of any 'InProgress' jobs.

   - I use an Azure Function to check the status of the ADF pipeline based on RunId.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your pipeline,

Go to Settings -> Concurrency -> Set to 1

This will set the number of runs of that pipeline to 1.Only 1 instance of the pipeline will run at a time. All the other pipeline runs will be queued.